# Short-term study visa + tourist visa

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, study, repeat-visits

I am an Australian coming to the UK in August for a tour of Europe, which begins in London. I will then be coming back at the beginning of September for a 6-month study abroad program at a UK university. I have been told that entering the UK more than a month before the beginning of my program would potentially be risky. I was wondering if I would run into any barriers with applying for a visa online?

- My period abroad would end up being less than 6 months: 5 months and 26 days
- I also have all necessary documentation.

I have also been advised that after entering on a tourist visa in August, getting a short-term study visa would be the best option. Does this carry any risks?

Would there be any issues with entering as a tourist, given that I would have the approved study visa for the next month? I'm more concerned that they would think that I was trying to stay for longer.

Comment: Would there be any issues with entering as a tourist, given that I would have the approved study visa for the next month? I'm more concerned that they would think that I was trying to stay for longer.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/australia/study/six_months_or_less You don’t need a study visa for up to 6 months provided you have been accepted on a course with an accredited Institution. A brief previous visa-free tourist visit should not be a problem provided that on arrival you can show proof of your intended departure. If in doubt, check with your local UK embassy/consulate

Comment: Getting a short-term student visa does not seem to carry any benefits, so it probably does not matter whether it carries any risks.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that you'd arrive in the UK to begin your time abroad, start with a trip throughout Europe, and enter a non-visa national. On your return, however, you may want to request entry at the UK border as a [Short-Term Student](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/722982/Short-term-students-guidance-v8.0-EXT.PDF).

With the documentation from the accredited university to which you have been accepted, you don't have to apply for a visa in advance of travelling, but request the correct immigration permission at the border. You would still get *leave to enter* but, as study is your main purpose, you so inform the Border Force Officer and your passport is stamped accordingly.

Comment: Is the passport stamp in fact different for a short-term student?

Comment: @phoog no, but the reason for entry recorded in the system, and a good idea for a non-visa national